# Using jQuery, how do I get the index of an element found in XML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an XML file setup like so:

```
<entry name="bob"></entry>
<entry name="ryan"></entry>
<entry name="joe"></entry>
...
<entry name="etc"></entry>
```

Next, I have a line of code that picks out a name from the XML like so:

```
var $user= $('entry[images="' + userName + '"]', xml);
```

But how do I find out what the index of $user is in the overall XML? Example: if userName was 'joe', I should get the number '2' back. Any suggestions?

Comment: The two answers below are correct. Here's an example I put together to offer a bit of extra help: http://jsfiddle.net/UnNwf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.index()` method: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is what you are looking for: 
http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `index()` method is your friend. Look at this jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    $("div p").each(function() {
        $(this).append( $(this).attr("name")+$(this).index() );
    });
};
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<p name="tom"></p>
<p name="dick"></p>
<p name="harry"></p>
</div>
```

will produce:

```
tom0

dick1

harry2
```